# How to hide ribbon in SP2013 for some users?

Tags: sharepoint

how to  hide the ribbon bar from anonymous user, Example for users that does not have managed web etc.

Comment: Check this [HOW TO HIDE THE SHAREPOINT 2013 RIBBON?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/12/hide-ribbon-sharepoint-2013-using-css/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)      Open your SharePoint master page

2)      Locate this line:
`<div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle">`

3)      Change it to:
`<div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle" style="display:none">`

4)      Now find the end of the `“s4-ribbonrow”` tag and add following block right after it:
`<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="AddAndCustomizePages">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "block";
    </script>`

5)      Save the new master page

OR

1. Add a LoginView control to the Sharepoint 2010 master page
2. Add AnonymousTemplate section to the LoginView Control
3. Place the entire SPRibbon control within the Anonymous template

Comment: Check this [HOW TO HIDE THE SHAREPOINT 2013 RIBBON?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/12/hide-ribbon-sharepoint-2013-using-css/)